# How to append elements in struct array without looping in matlab?

Tags: matlab, struct, append

I want to add elements in struct without looping like I have done below:

```
test_struct = struct ('item1', {} , 'item2' , {} ) ;
for k = 1 : 10
    test_struct(k).item1 = 1:10 ;
    test_struct(k).item2 = 2* (1:10) ;
end
```

Is there a way to add elements like adding elements in List in C#. I want a dynamic struct array because I do not know the how many elements, I will have to add in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
%%// First Data (normal arrays)
data1 = 1:10;
data2 = 2* (1:10);
test_struct1 = struct('item1', {data1}, 'item2', {data2});

%%// New Data (normal arrays) to be appended
data1 = 11:20;
data2 = 4* (1:15);

%%// Main step that appends new data
test_struct1(end+1) = struct('item1', {data1}, 'item2', {data2});
```

For verification, you may use this [nice tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43463-compare-two-structures) for comparing structures, as I don't think MATLAB has any built-in function for that, not in some of the previous versions of MATLAB at least.

Comment: Thanks. However I have still issues because I want to add normal arrays instead of cellarray.

Comment: @User1551892 Check out the edited code in `Method 1`. This might seal the deal for you!

Comment: I was looking something like you mentioned in Method1. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the struct statement itself:

```
A={1:10,1:10};
B={2*(1:10),2*(1:20)};
test_struct=struct('item1',A,'item2',B)
```